# Define $x^3$ = $x \times x^2$. Prove that if $x_1, x_2$, . . . represents $x$, then $x_1^3$, $x_2^3$, . . . represents $x^3$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I'm a little bit lost on where to start this problem. My initial thought is to work backwards. Say $x^3$ is a Cauchy sequence. Then for some $j, k \geq m$ contingent on $n$, we have |${x^3}_j - {x^3}_k$| $\leq$ $\frac{1}{n}$ . Since $x^3$ is defined as $x \times x^2$, perhaps we could define the Cauchy sequence as |$x_j$ - $x_k$| $\times$ |$x_j - x_k|^2$. Then maybe use a change in variable to bring about the desired result?

Would there be a more productive approach? This one doesn't seem that clear-cut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can factor: $|x_m^3 - x_n^3| = |x_m - x_n| |x_m^2 + x_m x_n + x_n^2|$. So if the sequence is bounded by $M$, then the factor there is bounded by $3M^2$, i.e. $|x_m^3 - x_n^3| \leq 3M^2 |x_m - x_n|$. That will tell you that $x_k^3$ is Cauchy. Can you take it from there to show that its limit is actually $x^3$?